# Ubuntu 10.04 eats more than 500MB of memory

Tags: memory-usage

After installation System monitor shows that memory usage is over 500 MB - pure system after start.

There are no processes which use more 20 MB of memory. Other versions of Ubuntu used about 200 MB. I'm using 64bit version. Intel i7, 16 GB of memory.

What's going on? What process are eating my memory?

Comment: How come you know that no process uses more than 20MB but you don't know which one uses how much?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116331/why-is-ubuntu-using-so-much-memory

Answer (score 2):

Enter `top` at the command line.

Then look at these two lines:

```
Mem:   8092444k total,  7647620k used,   444824k free,   550248k buffers
Swap:  8388604k total,   107804k used,  8280800k free,  3228520k cached
```

- Buffers is the amount of memory used for file system meta information like directories
- Cached is the amount of memory used as disk cache, for files

These two pools grow/shrink automatically, depending on the amount of memory actual processes require. When you have a lot of memory and only small process memory footprint, it is good that your RAM is used as disk cache as it improves system responsiveness. Your machine doesn't have to read the disk every time over and over again. On most machines (depending on RAM size) after a while nearly the whole memory will be in use, either for processes or as disk cache.

- Used (first line) is process memory + buffers + cached
- Free (first line) is readily available RAM
- Swap is the size of your swap space
- Used (second line) is amount of swap space in use
- Free (second line) is free swap space

Swap space is virtual memory, memory on disk rather than RAM. Having it is extremely valuable, but it is slow. The kernel provides a lot of intelligence to decide whether to swap out (unused) process memory or to give up some disk cache.

Comment: As a rule of thumb ... : Unused memory is wasted money ;o)