# Wrong display memory usage by htop command

Tags: ram, nginx

I use WordPress and Nginx in Ubuntu 20.04. I have a VPS with 2 cores and 4GB RAM, but the RAM has always been showing in `htop` under 1GB, but in my control panel I could see the RAM usage after about 24 hours gradually became full (4 GB).

Why did this happen? Is it normal? If not, what is my mistake?

[image: picture htop]

Comment: I see 597M used of 3.84GiB (~4 GB) total memory in your screenshot. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Ubuntu using so much memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116331/why-is-ubuntu-using-so-much-memory)

Comment: I mension that in my console ( the company's panel that I've purchased vps ) shows server is using full of memory.